# Equal columns in a table without knowing the number of columns just using html/CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

Bit of old school one i think but wondered if anyone had a solution for it by now:

Is there a way of getting equal columns in a table without knowing the number of columns just using html/CSS?

After the cleanest method possible really.

This is my test table at the moment:

```
<table class="panel-form panel-form_horizontal" style="width:100%;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="header">
        <h3>fieldset 1</h3>
        <menu>
          <button id="">edit</button>
        </menu>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>name</label></td>
      <td><label>name</label></td>
      <td><label>name</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>supplier_1</td>
      <td>www.bbc.co.uk</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" class="header">
        <h3>fieldset 2</h3>
        <menu>
          <button id="">edit</button>
        </menu>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>name</label></td>
      <td><label>name</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what do you mean by `equal columns`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no perfect solution to your question if you don't know the number of columns.

You can try:

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

This will force the table to use fixed, equal cells. The problem is if your content is too large for the cell size it'll cause issues with content overlap, etc.

Here's a basic sample using your markup: http://jsfiddle.net/9HC8b/. Notice when the screen width is wide enough everything looks great. If you start dragging (shrinking) the window you'll see the content blows up.

Comment: `word-wrap: break-word;` can help with long words and small widths. It works with IE and recent versions of modern browsers and when it doesn't work, well, you're simply back to the default.

Comment: ah cheers guys, thought the same tbh but wanted to see what the greatly community had to say about the subject. Didn't think of using table layout though thats for sure!  =)

Comment: @Felipe: good idea to go along with the table-layout - hadn't thought of this.